# Disable Submit Button for 1 min after Submit in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am learning Rails, I have faced a problem.
When I submit a form I get a pop up message to confirm.
If I press `Ok` then form will submit and button will be Disable, its working.

But when I cancel popup confirmation then submit button also gets disabled when it should not.

I want to disable Submit button for 1min after submit the form and if I cancel popup confirmation, the submit button should activate.

Please help me to solve the problem.

```
<%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => "btn btn-yellow", data: { disable_with: "Please wait..." }%>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess `date_disable_with` will be best suited in this case since it disables the submit button until the form submission completed.

If you want to disable the submit button exactly for 1 minute, you need to use javascript for that.

For `date_disable_with` to work you need to include [jquery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) and [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) in the page

Comment: In rails not possible ? set time ?

Comment: No, you need to use javascript.

Comment: You're welcome! :) Please consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try `data_disabled_with`? It will make the submit button disable automatically after first click, but will return to enabled if cancelled.

Check [this RoR API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag)

```
submit_tag
# => <input name="commit" data-disable-with="Save changes" type="submit" value="Save changes" />

submit_tag "Edit this article"
# => <input name="commit" data-disable-with="Edit this article" type="submit" value="Edit this article" />

submit_tag "Save edits", disabled: true
# => <input disabled="disabled" name="commit" data-disable-with="Save edits" type="submit" value="Save edits" />

submit_tag "Complete sale", data: { disable_with: "Submitting..." }
# => <input name="commit" data-disable-with="Submitting..." type="submit" value="Complete sale" />

submit_tag nil, class: "form_submit"
# => <input class="form_submit" name="commit" type="submit" />

submit_tag "Edit", class: "edit_button"
# => <input class="edit_button" data-disable-with="Edit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Edit" />

submit_tag "Save", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }
# => <input name='commit' type='submit' value='Save' data-disable-with="Save" data-confirm="Are you sure?" />
```

Comment: But I want it disable for 1min( 60s)

Comment: But you says `I want to disable Submit button for 1min after submit the form and if I cancel popup confirmation, the submit button should activate.` So it is not always 60s, no? How if user accidentally press the submit, then pop-up shown and cancel it right away? The button will not active yet cos not 60s yet, no?

Comment: yes Its not always 60s. If popup confirm Ok than 60s disable @ksugiarto

Comment: I see, I'm not sure about why you need to do that since it is not a best practice that way, unless for exact time-out of API or anything else. So how the progress? At least, have you tried the `data_disabled_with`?